# Unable to establish connection with SQL Server on LAN

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, ssms

I am on the verge of completing a project and I am stuck on establishing database connection with SQL Server. I have installed SQL Server Management Studio 2005 and whenever I try to make query from Client system to Server Server, it gives an error of `Access Denied`. Any idea on what the error can be?

```
Data Source=NEWNAME\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\DB\test1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the connection string you're trying to use?

Comment: "Data Source=NEWNAME\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\DB\test1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see that TCP-IP connections are enabled from the server? A lot of the time when testing locally on the server vs externally this can cause confusion.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb909712(v=vs.90).aspx

It's also worth double checking that the server exists and you can connnect to it locally via management studio.

Comment: Checked that. Done that. Even disabled firewall!

Comment: Have you tried the following:

http://www.sophos.com/en-us/support/knowledgebase/65525.aspx

You can use udl files to test database connectivity from different locations. Helping to prove the connection string works.